# JSON.stringify not working correctly

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON.stringify method to get string of json data returned from server.
I have noticed that my string Identificação gets converted to Identifica��o
Can you please suggest what can be done to keep the string as it is? I did try encodeURIcomponenet that did not work.

Comment: What does Java have to do with this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: The problem is not in JSON.stringify. Check that the character encoding is correct. It's probably a mix up between UTF8 and ISO8859-1

Comment: Adding code below:

Answer (score 0):

I would check the network tab in your chrome console. Check the response that is coming from the server. You will find that is already wrong before JSON.stringify.

If you are using maven. Try to set those properties in the pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this.

```
         var obj={
           a:'Identificação0',
           b:'755'
           };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));//{"a":"Identificação0","b":"755"}
```

It is printing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Weird symbols appear when you add text on html page?
If so, add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside your `<head>`